# Exception handling data in Pandas apply

Tags: python, pandas

I have built a function that is using regex to set date formats. However my data has `nan` values in it and I would ideally like to handle them in the main function.

How can I take all the `nan` value rows and `append` them to an empty list? I have done this before but not as part of exception handling!

In my head I'm thinking of something like a case when, then else statement from SQL to do here to handle the exceptions in code.

This is what I have now:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
import re

def conv_date(dte: str) -> date:
    acceptable_mappings = {
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}": "%d-%m-%Y",
        "\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}": "%Y/%m/%d",
        "\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}": "%d/%m/%Y",
        "\d{8}": '%d%m%Y',
        "\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}": '%d %m %Y',
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\D{1}\d{2}\D{1}\d{2}\s\w{3}": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z",

    }
    # for loop to iterate through our allowed mappings and return value, else raise an exception
    for regex in acceptable_mappings.keys():
        if re.fullmatch(regex, dte):
            return datetime.strptime(dte, acceptable_mappings[regex]).date()
    raise Exception(f"Expected date is not in one of the supported formats, got ***{dte}***")
```

And the test:

```
from x import conv_date
import pytest
from datetime import datetime, date
import pandas as pd

def test_mock_dict(self):
    # Use this data to test the dates function for humans to interpret. Name and role are added for readability
    mock_dict = [
        {"name": "dz", "role": "legend", "date": "2023-07-26"},
        {"name": "mc", "role": "sounds like a dj", "date": "26-07-2023"},
        {"name": "xc", "role": "loves xcom", "date": "2023/07/26"},
        {"name": "lz", "role": "likes to fly", "date": "26/07/2023"},
        {"name": "wc", "role": "has a small bladder", "date": "26072023"},
        {"name": "aa", "role": "warrior of the crystal", "date": "26 07 2023"},
        {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": "2023-07-26 12:46:21"},
        {"name": "jm", "role": "is stack overflow", "date": "2023-10-26 12:46:21 UTC"},
        {"name": "ee", "role": "enjoys nan bread", "date": "nan"},
    ]

    df = pd.DataFrame(mock_dict)

    print(df)
    df['date_clean'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: conv_date(x))
    print(df)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off I think that your test case is a bit unclear about what you are actually trying to achieve since it doesn't actually have an assert statement. My interpretation is that if you have problematic rows you want to remove them from the incoming data and append them to an error list instead.

To reflect this I would update the tests to look something like:

```py
from x import conv_date, clean_data
from datetime import datetime, date
from math import nan


class TestDateConversions:
    def test_without_errors(self):
        # Use this data to test the dates function for humans to interpret. Name and role are added for readability
        input_list = [
            {"name": "dz", "role": "legend", "date": "2023-07-26"},
            {"name": "mc", "role": "sounds like a dj", "date": "26-07-2023"},
            {"name": "xc", "role": "loves xcom", "date": "2023/07/26"},
            {"name": "lz", "role": "likes to fly", "date": "26/07/2023"},
            {"name": "wc", "role": "has a small bladder", "date": "26072023"},
            {"name": "aa", "role": "warrior of the crystal", "date": "26 07 2023"},
            {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": "2023-07-26 12:46:21"},
            {
                "name": "jm",
                "role": "is stack overflow",
                "date": "2023-10-26 12:46:21 UTC",
            },
        ]

        expected_output_list = [
            {"name": "dz", "role": "legend", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "mc", "role": "sounds like a dj", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "xc", "role": "loves xcom", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "lz", "role": "likes to fly", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "wc", "role": "has a small bladder", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "aa", "role": "warrior of the crystal", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {
                "name": "jm",
                "role": "is stack overflow",
                "date": date(2023, 10, 26),
            },
        ]

        assert (expected_output_list, []) == clean_data(input_list)

    def test_with_error(self):
        # Use this data to test the dates function for humans to interpret. Name and role are added for readability
        input_list = [
            {"name": "dz", "role": "legend", "date": "2023-07-26"},
            {"name": "mc", "role": "sounds like a dj", "date": "26-07-2023"},
            {"name": "xc", "role": "loves xcom", "date": "2023/07/26"},
            {"name": "lz", "role": "likes to fly", "date": "26/07/2023"},
            {"name": "wc", "role": "has a small bladder", "date": "26072023"},
            {"name": "aa", "role": "warrior of the crystal", "date": "26 07 2023"},
            {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": "2023-07-26 12:46:21"},
            {
                "name": "jm",
                "role": "is stack overflow",
                "date": "2023-10-26 12:46:21 UTC",
            },
            {"name": "ee", "role": "enjoys nan bread", "date": nan},
        ]

        expected_output_list = [
            {"name": "dz", "role": "legend", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "mc", "role": "sounds like a dj", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "xc", "role": "loves xcom", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "lz", "role": "likes to fly", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "wc", "role": "has a small bladder", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "aa", "role": "warrior of the crystal", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {"name": "xx", "role": "loves only-fans", "date": date(2023, 7, 26)},
            {
                "name": "jm",
                "role": "is stack overflow",
                "date": date(2023, 10, 26),
            },
        ]

        expected_error_list = [{"name": "ee", "role": "enjoys nan bread", "date": nan}]

        assert (expected_output_list, expected_error_list) == clean_data(input_list)
```

Your date cleaning function is actually working as expected I think as it throws an error. However using a dataframe apply is probably not the correct solution if you want to create a new error list. In file `x` I suggest writing a cleaning function that uses the `conv_date` function and creates the error list you are after. It would look something like:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
import re


def conv_date(dte: str) -> date:
    acceptable_mappings = {
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d",
        "\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}": "%d-%m-%Y",
        "\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}": "%Y/%m/%d",
        "\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}": "%d/%m/%Y",
        "\d{8}": "%d%m%Y",
        "\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{4}": "%d %m %Y",
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}\D{1}\d{2}\D{1}\d{2}\s\w{3}": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z",
    }
    # for loop to iterate through our allowed mappings and return value, else raise an exception
    for regex in acceptable_mappings.keys():
        if re.fullmatch(regex, dte):
            return datetime.strptime(dte, acceptable_mappings[regex]).date()
    raise Exception(
        f"Expected date is not in one of the supported formats, got ***{dte}***"
    )


def clean_data(input_list: list) -> set[list, list]:
    # take in a list and clean the data field. Output a cleaned list and a list of errors

    err_list = []

    for item in input_list:
        try:
            item["date"] = conv_date(item["date"])
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            input_list.remove(item)
            err_list.append(item)

    return input_list, err_list
```

By doing this you are able to clean any data that processes and can then correctly handle your error list (either by flagging an alert or exporting).